# How to save the contents of a plain text file on the phones storage to a variable in Android?

Tags: android

I have some plain text data in the external storage of an android device and I want to save that plain text to a variable how could I do that?

I tried:

```
Scanner in;
try {
in = new Scanner(openFileInput("aspw.dat"));
String password = in.nextLine();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
errortoast.show();
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get a file not found exception even though the file aspw.dat is right there in the root of the SD card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(openFileInput("Name of file"));
String stuff = in.nextLine();
```

`stuff` will then contain the contents of the first line in your file. You can keep calling `in.nextLine()` if there is supposed to be more than one line in the file. For more information on using scanners checkout the [Scanner Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). For more on using android file input and output checkout the documentation for [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).